# Show that a linear form $\mathbb{R}^n \to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

$f(x)$=$n∑k=1$ $g$($x_k$) ou $x_k$ is the kth component of the vector x. $x_k=\langle e_k,x\rangle$.

I have the option of showing this with sequences (which I dont know how, I never understood how to show that a function is continuous using sequences), or with $f(x + h) - f(x) = \sum g(x_k + h_k) - g(x_k)$ where the limit goes to $0$.

I don't get how to show continuity. I don't understand the concept of continuity here :/

Comment: I'm confused by this question. Can you define your terms more clearly ($f(x)$, $n$, $x_k$, $e_k$, etc.)?  Can you precisely state what you are trying to prove?

Comment: I tried to fix the $\LaTeX$ as best as I could, but the very first part is incomprehensible.

Comment: The first part should probably be $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n g(x_k)$, but it is unclear what $g$ is.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous if for every open $U\subset Y$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. Now this definition is the general topological definition. If you're not familiar with this, ignore this definition.

You probably know that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a metric space or normed space. Hence we can reformulate the definition of continuity as follows:

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if for every open interval $(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}((a,b))$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. for each $x\in f^{-1}((a,b))$ there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that the ball $B(x,\varepsilon)$ centered at $x$ with radius $\varepsilon$ is contained in $f^{-1}((a,b))$.

It's an excellent exercise to show the following:

The function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if and only if for each convergent sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $x_n\rightarrow x$ one has that $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$.

As for your question, I agree with felipeh, you should formulate it more clearly, I don't quite understand the problem.